# IronSource Banner in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin, banner, ironsource

I want to integrate a Banner Ad from Ironsource but have some problems to get it working.

[This](https://developers.ironsrc.com/ironsource-mobile/xamarin/banner-integration-xamarin-android/) is the documentation, but I have problems to integrate it.
Thay say, that I have to write a bannerContainer, but how do I implement it in my XML-View like my main menu?

For this example to work you are going to need a .xml file, to describe this bannerContainer:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/bannerContainer"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This file is in Project.Android/Resources/xml/bannerContainer.xml

After this, I have to add folowing code to my MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    // YOUR OTHER CODE //
    // YOUR OTHER CODE //
    // YOUR OTHER CODE //
    IronSource.Init(this, "YOUR_APP_KEY", IronSource.AD_UNIT.Banner);

    FrameLayout bannerContainer = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.bannerContainer);
    IronSourceBannerLayout mBanner = IronSource.CreateBanner(this, ISBannerSize.Banner);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    bannerContainer.addView(mBanner, 0, layoutParams);
```

but at this point

```
bannerContainer.addView(mBanner, 0, layoutParams);
```

The bannerContainer throws a NullReferenceException...

And still I dont know how to implement the banner in my "normal" views like in my MainMenu. All this code is in my project.Android, but I have my views in my pcl project, how to get access to the banner in the Android part?

Chris

Comment: Which object is null?

Comment: the bannerContainer

Comment: You are loading the `Main` layout (`SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main)`), is the xaml of the `FrameLayout` layout contained within that layout?

Comment: no, I never touched that files before. How do I do that? And how do I implement then that banner layout in my other views?